# windows 7 samba login error

Tags: windows-7, samba

I have a problem login to Samba server from windows 7. Samba works perfectly with all other PCs running Windows 10.

When I'm trying to login to Samba, login dialog appears with written login name which consists the of the localPCname\username, asking only password. I can choose login with other account, but under domain there is still the local PC name on this Windows 7 machine.

This PC is not in domain and I have tried to make "this is a home computer it's not part of a business network" in "properties of my computer - change - etc--

Pictures of the login dialogs: [samba1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgAfL.jpg), [samba2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeH5h.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If the Samba-server is on domain, choose "Use another account" and then type both Domain and username in format `DOMAIN\username`. If the Samba-server is not part of your domain, you can use `.\usersname` or `SAMBASERVER\username` to avoid using the local computer as the domain part.

Comment: I`ve forgot to mention that I can see the main samba folder which is "name" and has a description "share" all errors I get when trying to access it.
SAMBASERVER.\username - I get the same login dialog as in my second picture in question, UNDER domain which is pcName, not just user login. Then I get the same as in first my picture.

Comment: Could you add corresponding log events from `/var/log/samba/` into your original question for further investigation, please.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what did help was to setup Samba-related password using command:
`sudo smbpasswd -a username` where "username" must be a login from the Linux box. Then on Windows box you use this login and the password set by this command and it works.

Related documentation: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share